# Define a function using output of another function

Tags: functions, assignment

I am away from my computer and therefore unable to experiment, but I am keen to scribble down a few Mathematica operations in note form ready for my return. So, forgive the simplistic question…

Say I define some very complicated numerical function `f[x_] := …` which has an integral that takes a long time for Mathematica to calculate. It makes sense to define the integral as a new function so that Mathematica doesn’t recalculate it each time. Of course, it’s easy enough to evaluate `Integrate[f[x],x]`…

…but how do I assign the *output* a new function name, say `fIntegral[x]`, so that Mathematica doesn’t recalculate each time? Obviously,  I don’t want to write

```
 fIntegral[x_] := Integrate[f[x],x]
```

because then the software will evaluate `Integrate[f[x],x]` each time I use `fIntegral[x]`.

Can I write

```
Integrate[f[x],x];
fIntegral[x_] := %
```

or would that not work?

CONTEXT

The question above was simplified for clarity.

The integral expression (Abel summation) for a sum from `k = a`  to `b` of a function `f[k]` contains the expression `Integrate[x * D[f[x], x], {x, a, b}]`. I want to be able to experiment with both `D[f[x], x]` and `Integrate[x * D[f[x], x], {x, a, b}]` without Mathematica recalculating them each time - and also without manually redefining them each time I change `f`.

Comment: **so that Mathematica doesn’t recalculate each time?** One possible way is to replace `fIntegral[x_] := Integrate[f[x],x]` with `fIntegral[x_] = Integrate[f[x],x]` without knowing the full context of your code, do not know if this will work for you or not.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser. I’ll  check it out when I am at my desk. I have added a note about context to the OP.

Comment: @Nasser, adding that context took some time, sorry! I’m on my phone with lousy signal…

Comment: A technique called memonization  may help: int[x_]:= int[x]= Integral[...

Comment: As here: <https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html>? Looks promising… I’d be happy to mark as answered if you want to post it as one 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users), specifically the section [Understand the difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/26598).

Comment: All incredibly useful responses. Many thanks 